# How to display values in the same line in Crystal Report

Tags: csv, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

I want to display result in crystal report in same line for example i have :

1.

```
             G1      
             
                a         b         c

                d         e         f

                g         h         i
```

and i want :

```
     G1    

                a        b          c            d           e       f        g      h      i
```

Comment: Can you fix the max number of fields per line?

Answer (score 0):

If you can fix the max number of fields per line:

1. Section expert
2. Details section
3. Format with multiple columns
4. Layout tab
5. Width = set the desired width of each column
6. Printing direction = across and down